# Rotate Around Multiple Axes without Parent Child Relation - OpenGL Shaders

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, parent-child, pyopengl

I'm trying to rotate an object around multiple axes using PyOpenGL with shaders. Because there is no glRotatef() like in old OpenGL, I'm using 4x4 rotation matrices. However since matrix multiplication is not commutative, it establishes this parent child relation, where one axis rotates independently (parent), and the other axis rotates based on the first axis (child). I am not super familiar with matrices, I just began AP precalc and I haven't gotten to matrices, but from what I know there is no way to multiply rotation matrices without establishing this relationship.

Here's the sample of the program.

```
model1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                        [0, cos(player_rotation_x), sin(player_rotation_x), 0],
                        [0, -sin(player_rotation_x), cos(player_rotation_x), 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 1]
             ]) @ np.array([[cos(-player_rotation_z), -sin(-player_rotation_z), 0, 0],
                            [sin(-player_rotation_z), cos(-player_rotation_z), 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 1, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]
             ]) @ np.array([[cos(player_rotation_y), 0, -sin(player_rotation_y), 0],
                            [0, 1, 0, 0],
                            [sin(player_rotation_y), 0, cos(player_rotation_y), 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

This establishes a hierarchy from x to y.

Here's the the sample of the program from I'm trying to recreate with shaders instead of the fixed function pipeline.

```
rotation_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

while True:
    glPushMatrix()
    glLoadIdentity()
    glRotatef(-player_rotation_x, 1, 0, 0)
    glRotatef(-player_rotation_y, 0, 1, 0)
    glMultMatrixf(rotation_matrix)
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, rotation_matrix)
    glPopMatrix()
```

Comment: Matrix multiplication is NOT commutative, A·B is not equal to B·A, order matters. If don't change the origin, you can "chain" rotations (or other transformations) in a single matrix. For example if "A" represents a rotation around "X" axis and then, later, you apply a rotation "B" around "Y" axis, the resultant matrix `C=A·B` can give you directly both rotations.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "not", I'm trying to achieve the opposite where I can combine the matrices without the order mattering, while rotating the object on multiple axis. Essentially making it so no matter how its been rotated, all the rotations act the same way

Comment: Order matters **always**, you can't avoid it. What's "*all rotations act the same way*"?

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). When matrices are multiplied, the order matters, that is a mathematical fact. There is a big difference between the two code snippets in your question. While the first creates a completely new matrix based on the rotations,

```
model = rX * rZ * rY
```

the second (legacy OpenGL) updates the current model matrix by concatenating it with the new rotations

```
model = rX * rY * model
```

Do not sum up the angles, but change the model transformation progressively, as it is the case in the legacy OpenGL code. That means, if you are doing `player_rotation_x += rotation_x`, you should not use `player_rotation_x` but `rotation_x` to calculate the rotation matrix. Init the model matrix with the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix):

```py
model = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Calculate the rotation matrices based on the new delta rotation angles and concatenate them with the model matrix:

```py
rX = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, cos(rotation_x), sin(rotation_x), 0],
    [0, -sin(rotation_x), cos(rotation_x), 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]])
rZ = np.array([[cos(-rotation_z), -sin(-rotation_z), 0, 0],
    [sin(-rotation_z), cos(-rotation_z), 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]])
rY = np.array([[cos(rotation_y), 0, -sin(rotation_y), 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [sin(rotation_y), 0, cos(rotation_y), 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1]])
model = rX @ rZ @ rY @ model
```

---

You can simplify that code using [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/) or [Pyrr](https://pypi.org/project/pyrr/). Here is the example implemented with PyGlm.

Import PyGlm

```py
import glm
```

Initialize the matrix

```py
model = glm.mat4(1)
```

Create the rotation matrices and multiply with the model matrix:

```py
rotation = glm.rotate(glm.mat4(1), rotation_x, glm.vec3(1, 0, 0))
rotation = glm.rotate(rotation, rotation_z, glm.vec3(0, 0, 1)) *
rotation = glm.rotate(rotation, rotation_y, glm.vec3(0, 1, 0)) *
model = rotation * model;
```

Comment: @user23094234 Please read carefully the part of the answer that starts with *"Do not add the angles ... " *. Anyway, I can only give suggestions based on the code in your question. You have to debug and fix your code yourself.